# C# Powershell cmdlet, Invoke method not working in tests

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm creating a custom powershell cmdlet using System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.

Following is the cmdlet. However, when calling Invoke() method in test, BeginProcessing//EndProcessing/ProcessRecord are not getting invoked. Can't call these methods directly as well since they have protected visibility. Please let me know, what am I missing.

```
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Set, "Flag")]
    [OutputType(typeof(string))]
    public class FlagCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        [Alias("Operation")]
        [ValidateSet("Start", "End", "Get")]
        public string Operation { get; set; }

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        [Alias("Gate")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        public string Gate { get; set; }

        private StoreRepo repo;

        public FlagCmdlet()
        {
            // initialize repo
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            switch (this.Operation)
            {
                case "Start":
                    var flagRecord = // some logic
                    WriteObject(flagRecord);
                    break;
                case "End":
                    var flagRecord = // some logic
                    WriteObject(flagRecord);
                    break;
                case "Get":
                    var flagRecord = // some logic
                    WriteObject(flagRecord);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Test code to invoke it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestBadBuildCmdlet()
{
    var flagCmdlet = new FlagCmdlet();

    flagCmdlet.Operation = "Start";
    flagCmdlet.Gate = "test";
    flagCmdlet.Invoke();

    badBuildCmdlet.Operation = "Get";
    var res = badBuildCmdlet.Invoke().OfType<FlagRecord>().ToList().First();
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Your cmdlet never calls `WriteObject()` or similar - why would you expect it to output anything?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing quickly. It does use WriteObject... I skipped it in //some logic comment. It also make a change in backend store before calling WriteObject. None of the changes are getting applied.

Comment: Try removing `.OfType<FlagRecord>()` <- `Invoke()` will return your `FlagRecord` objects, but they will be _wrapped_ in `PSObject` instances - and `OfType()` won't return anything

Comment: If I put a debug point in BeginProcessing/EndProcessing/ProcessRecord, I don't see control entering any of the method on calling invoke.

Comment: What PowerShell library are you using in the Test project? If you’re using the StandardLibrary, it won’t work. You have to use the Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.